# Average time calced for a group of datetime detail lines in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a SSRS report in which I need to calculate the average time elapsed between two datetime fields contained in a group of detail rows. I have tried the following with the textbox defined as a time format `hh:mm:ss`.

```
=avg(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!ProcessOpened.Value, Fields!ProcessClosed.Value))
```

I get the following result.

```
H:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=Format(DateAdd("s",
Avg(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second,Fields!ProcessOpened.Value,Fields!ProcessClosed.Value))
,"00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```